# Rescale part of a matrix to bound the maximum eigenvalue module

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning

I am working with a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ with structure:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\ a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$

I would like to rescale the first two rows to make sure that the module of the maximum eigenvalue of the resulting matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ is lower or equal to a given constant $c$. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $p$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $C_p$ be the companion matrix of $p$.

According to the Gerschgorin theorem, the complex eigenvalues of $A$ are in the following union of euclidean balls in $\mathbb{C}$.

i) With the matrix $C_p$.

$B(0,|-ch+gd|)\cup B(0,|-ha+bg-cf+ed|+1)$

$\cup B(0,|-fa+eb+c+h|+1)\cup B(f+a,1)$.

ii) With the matrix $A$.

$B(a,|b|+|c|+|d|)\cup B(f,|g|+|h|+|e|)\cup B(0,1)$.

Remark 1. In both cases, we obtain $3$ or $1$ ball of radius $\geq 1$.

Remark 2. If $c=d=g=h=0$, then $spectrum(A)=\{0,0\}\cup spectrum(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\e&f\end{pmatrix})$.

EDIT. If you want $\rho(A)<1$, then do as follows.

Let $U=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\e&f\end{pmatrix},V=\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\g&h\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\det(A-\lambda I_4)=\det((U-\lambda I_2)(-\lambda I_2)-V)=\det(\lambda^2I_2-\lambda U -V)$.

If you want a small $\rho(A)$, then choose a small $\det(V)$ and a small $\rho(U)$, that is, small $a+f,af-be$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your second term in the determinant formula after the edit. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices